# yii2 odd/even listview with load more pagination

Tags: pagination, lazy-loading, yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components

First data loading is fine but when i click on load more my second page data going inside even div only.
I am generating list like this:

```
<div class="odd">
    <items>item1</items>
    <items>item3</items>
    <items>item5</items>
    <items>item7</items>
</div>

<div class="even">
    <items>item2</items>
    <items>item4</items>    
    <items>item6</items>
    <items>item8</items>
</div>
```

With this custom ListView class:

```
class ListViewOdd extends ListView
{
public function renderItems()
    {
        $models = $this->dataProvider->getModels();
        $keys = $this->dataProvider->getKeys();
        $rowsOdd = $rowsEven = [];
        foreach (array_values($models) as $index => $model) {
            if ($index%2 == 0) {
                 $rowsOdd[] = $this->renderItem($model, $keys[$index], $index);
            } else {
                 $rowsEven[] = $this->renderItem($model, $keys[$index], $index);
            }
        }
        return '<div class="odd">'.implode($this->separator, $rowsOdd) . '</div><div class="even">'.implode($this->separator, $rowsOdd) .'</div>'; // replace <div> to Html::tag('div', ...)
    }
}


echo ListViewOdd::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_post',

]);
```

But load more pagination not splitting data again into odd/even listing as my first data list.

i am not passing anything from controller and action i am using model to get data provider

```
<?php echo ListViewOdd::widget([ 
'dataProvider' => Posts::getCommonListData($industry,'user','engage',0),
            'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item post-item'],
            'summary' => '',
            'id' => 'my-listview-id',
            'itemView' => '_Posts',
            'viewParams' => [
                  'fullView' => true,
                ],
            'pager' => [
            'class' => \app\vendor\kop\y2sp\ScrollPager::className(),
            //'negativeMargin' => '200',
            'triggerText' => 'Load More',
            //'triggerOffset' => 3,
            'noneLeftText' => '',
            ],  
        ]);

getting output like this

<div class="odd">
    <items>item1</items>
    <items>item3</items>
    <items>item5</items>
    <items>item7</items>
</div>

<div class="even">
    <items>item2</items>
    <items>item4</items>    
    <items>item6</items>
    <items>item8</items>
    <items>item9</items>
    <items>item10</items>    
    <items>item11</items>
    <items>item12</items>
</div>
```

after clicking loadmore its just loading all records inside even div and load more aoption also coming under even div

Comment: Please, show screenshots. And show controller action.

Comment: added somemore details to get clear idea @vitalik_74

Answer (score 0):

Change in method `renderItems`:

```
return '<div class="odd">'.implode($this->separator, $rowsOdd) . '</div><div class="even">'.implode($this->separator, $rowsEven) .'</div>';
```

Mistake is ''.implode($this->separator, $rowsOdd) .''.
Div is `even`, but data from `$rowsOdd` :)

Comment: Yes i already changed this but still getting same output
return '<div class="odd">'.implode($this->separator, $rowsOdd) . '</div><div class="even">'.implode($this->separator, $rowsEven) .'</div>';